# Slide In and Slide Out images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to achieve a smooth effect where, while one image is sliding out, another slides in. This animation needs to be in a way that while one thing is sliding out the other one is sliding in such that they both take up space inside the div at the same time.

Something like [this](http://www.mykindofphone.com/) or [this](http://www.ibm.com/in/en/)

I created a [simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C62uC/3/), describing the problem that he faced.

```
    $("#googleLogo").hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 500 );
    $("#yahooLogo").show("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500 );
```

I am basically sliding one thing out just before I start sliding the other one in. I think I am making a silly mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on your markup and style structure:

#### CSS:

```
#imageSliding {
   position:relative;
   height:100px;
}
#imageSliding img {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
#yahooLogo {
  display:none;
}
```

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C62uC/14/), might be you want something like this.